# How can I measure the performance of my jQuery tmpl templates when running under knockout.js

Tags: performance, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have a page that uses knockout.js with several tmpl templates. I believe something to do with the templates is killing the page's performance.

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template1">

</script>  

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template2">
  // I call template 3
</script>  

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template3">

</script>  

...etc...
```

**As I have many templates, some which call other templates, how do I find out which template is creating the performance problem?**

For example, can I run some javascript in each template to measure how long they are taking to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there are any built-in tools to do that in knockout.js, but you could try tweaking the source code of knockout.js and adding the logging you need. Template binding is defined [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/templating/templating.js). Find "ko.bindingHandlers['template'] = ..." and add your logging in 'update' function.